# Avoid manipulation of distributed cache

Tags: spring, security, caching, ehcache, jcs

I plan to use JCS or ehcache in Spring Cache and put this into a REST based webservice. The webservice will be distributed across at least two application servers. Because of this I plan to use a distributed cache.
From my understanding this means the cache service needs to be accessible via the network. During the research I did I found nothing about securing the connection. So I fear that someone knowing that the cache service is running will be able to manipulate the data.

Can I and if yes how can I secure JCS or ehcache in a distributed cache configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of ehcache, if you want to go to a distributed cache with inter-node security then their commercial product [BigMemory Max](http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/bigmemorymax/terracotta-server-array/managing-security) gives that functionality.

According to their [documentation](http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/bigmemorymax/terracotta-server-array/managing-security):

> You can choose one of the following to secure servers:
>
> SSL-based security – Provides certificate-based authentication for all
>   nodes (including clients) and secures the entire cluster with
>   encrypted connections. Can be used with role-based authorization.
>   LDAP-based authentication – Uses your organization's authentication
>   database to secure access to Terracotta servers.

Comment: Thanks for that detailled link. Do you know of a possibility to secure the cache without going (and paying) for the enterprise edition ?

Comment: I think it's not possible with ehcache, the distributed and secured version is their commercial product. Have a look at http://memcached.org/ and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029366/hibernate-ehcache-vs-memcache